# How do I determine whether angle A or B is closer to angle C?

Tags: algorithm

I want to calculate whether angle A or B is closer to angle C. I'm sure this is really easy but the way angles return to 0 at 360 and vice versa is confusing me as to how I'm supposed to compare them.

Right now I'm doing something like this, but this is wrong:

```
    similarity1 := degree - targetAngle1
    if (similarity1 > 360){
        similarty1 := 360 - similarity1
    }
    similarity2 := degree - targetAngle2
    if (similarity2 > 360){
        similarty2 := 360 - similarity2
    }
    if (similarity1 < similarity2){
        degree := similarity1
    } else {
        degree := similarity2
    }
```

The answer must be really simple but for some reason the problem has me confused.

Comment: I realize this is a language-agnostic question, but I'm curious - what language is this with both braces and `:=`?

Comment: @MarkRansom Autohotkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with numbers in the range of -180 to 180, you can simply compare the absolute value to see which is less.

To get the numbers into the -180 to 180 range, you must recognize that adding or subtracting 360 from the angle doesn't change it at all.

```
similarity1 := degree - targetAngle1
if (similarity1 > 180){
    similarty1 := similarity1 - 360
}
else if (similarity1 < -180){
    similarity1 := similarity1 + 360
}
similarity2 := degree - targetAngle2
if (similarity2 > 180){
    similarty2 := similarity2 - 360
}
else if (similarity2 < -180){
    similarity2 := similarity2 + 360
}
if (abs(similarity1) <= abs(similarity2)){
    degree := similarity1
} else {
    degree := similarity2
}
```

Comment: I'm going to assume I'm the one making a mistake here, but I tested your answer with no other code and hard-coded inputs just to make sure flawed inputs weren't the issue, and I didn't get either of the potential angles as a result. 

Here's the exact code I'm testing:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b239171b392917733ee4d8b01567cefc

And if you want to run it to see for yourself, [you can install AHK](https://autohotkey.com/download/) and just double click the script file to run it, then a log.txt will appear in the script directory with the results, as shown in the script.

Comment: I tried inputting potential angles 190 (A) and 10 (B) related to 90 (C) and the result was -80. Which even if I normalize that to be within 360 degrees, it still comes out to 280. I think you get what my goal is, to select one of the two angles, 190 or 10, based on which one is closer to 90. 

I probably made a mistake but I don't see where.

Comment: @Viziionary I view your problem as 3 positions on a compass, and given one of those positions you're trying to select whichever of the other 2 is closest. Am I correct? In your example, 10 is 80 degrees from 90 while 190 is 100 degrees from 90 so 10 is the closest. The problem might lie in the final assignment, use `degree := targetAngle1` instead of `degree := similarity1`.

Comment: That makes sense, woops!

Answer (score 0):

Approach without multiple conditions, but with trigonometric function call:

```
if Cos(C-A) > Cos(C-B) then
    A closer to C
```